# Do tmux sessions automatically close after a while?

Tags: command-line, ssh, tmux

I initiated 10 tmux sessions with the following command (the value is from 2007 to 2017):

```
tmux new-session -d -s my2017 "python myscript.py 2017"
```

After initiating all these sessions, I first exited from my remote Ubuntu machine which I connected via SSH. And then logged in again and ran the following command:

```
tmux list-sessions
```

And I confirmed that the sessions were run there (the programs should had finished).

However, a few days later I logged in to the remote machine again, and ran the same `tmux list-sessions` command, I found the sessions were gone, with the following message:

```
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1001/default
```

Does the session automatically stop after a while in tmux? If so, what is the criterion of them being gone, and can I regain the session again? I would like to know what the program logged out in the console in a separate sessions...

Comment: Either the command terminated by itself or somebody else terminated it (e. g. a system administrator who doesn't want long running processes to hog system resources). What do you want to achieve here? To interact with the application and see its output even after its termination?

Answer (score 0):

If it is anything like `screen`, the session that you started like that ends when your command ran through. (As it would as well if you exit your shell)